# debug session ends prematurely with vs.net 2008IE8

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, internet-explorer-8

After upgrading to IE8, I have trouble debugging my web application (using development server). When I hit a breakpoint and start stepping over the code, all of a sudden my debug session ends prematurely.

Any clues whats going on, and suggestions to fix this?

P.S. I have installed Silverlight Tools and chose Silverlight debugging to disable IE debugging, but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a fix for this, but there is some sort of solution.
**Using another browser**, I selected Chrome, and now looks like I can debug my code again:)